# IIS Erro 401 ao enviar imagem para diretorio do iis com php

Tags: php, asp, iis, file-upload, iis-7

estou tendo um problema com envio de imamgens.
tenho um script php que envia uma imagem para uma pasta no iis, pois é utilizada por scripts asp. mas toda vez que eu faço esse envio e tento abrir a imagem no browser é retornado erro 401. se enviado por script em asp funciona.

mas preciso que seja enviado pelo php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, alterei no php.ini o diretório de upload temporários para uma pasta com permissões do windows.

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir